# Is this a compact operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Define $T: L^1 [0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1] $ as
$$Tf(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$$
In my understanding it's compact since 
$$sup | \int_0^x f_n(t)dt - \int_0^xf_m(t)dt | \leq  \int_0^x |f_n(t) -f_m(t)|dt \leq \int_0^1 |f_n(t) -f_m(t)|dt = \Vert f_n-f_m\Vert_1$$
So for any convergence sequence $\{f_n\} \in L{[0,1]}$, $\{Tf_n\} $ is a convergence sequence in $ C{[0,1]}$.

But the answer is that the operator is noncompact. What goes wrong?

Comment: Compactness of an operator doesn't mean that it takes convergent sequences to convergent sequences. Rather it means it takes bounded sequences to sequences possessing a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Do you know how to prove it's noncompact? Thanks

Comment: I suspect the image of the unit ball is not an equicontinuous set of functions, and you can apply Arzela-Ascoli.

Comment: You only showed that $\|T\| \le 1$, that is, that $T$ is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

No, this operator is not compact. Let $f_n=nI_{(0,\frac  1n)}$. Then $(f_n)$ is bounded in $L^{1}[0,1]$. Now $Tf_n (x) = 1$ for $x >\frac 1 n$ and $Tf_n(0)=0$. This implies that $(Tf_n)$ conveges pointwise to the discontinuous function $f$ defined by $f(x)=1$ for $x >0$ and $f(0)=0$. Hence $T(f_n)$ cannot have any subsequence converging uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the Volterra operator, and indeed it is compact. It is an integral operator of the form
$$ 
Tf(x) = \int_0^1 K(x,t)f(t)\ \mathsf dt
$$
with kernel $K(x,t) = \mathsf1_{(0,x)}(t)$. Now by Tonelli's theorem we have
$$
\int_{[0,1]^2} |K(x,t)|^2\ \mathsf d(x\times t) = \int_0^1\int_0^x \ \mathsf dt\ \mathsf dx = \frac12<\infty,
$$
so that $K\in L^2([0,1]^2)$. It follows that $T$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator and thus is compact, as an operator from $L^2([0,1])$ to $L^2([0,1])$.

However, as pointed out by @Kabo Murphy's answer, $T$ is not compact considered as an operator from $L^1([0,1])$ to $C([0,1])$.

Comment: It's $L^1 [0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$

Comment: At least, $T$ is compact as an operator from $L^2([0,1])\to L^2([0,1])$. As an operator from $L^1([0,1])\to C([0,1])$ it may not be. I suppose we need to find a bounded sequence $f_n$ in $L^1([0,1])$ such that $Tf_n$ does not have a convergent subsequence in $C([0,1])$.